# How to read & save the output of OV7670 camera for arduino UNO in rust?

Tags: c++, rust, arduino, embedded

## What am I doing

I am using [this code](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/how-to-use-ov7670-camera-module-with-arduino) on my arudino uno project with OV7670 camera. It works well. With a help of this tool named "Serial Port Reader"(which I downloaded from the link in article) I am able to view the image from my camera (windows only).

I am trying to rewrite this tool for reading images in rust (cause I wanna use it on mac).
I've successfully connected and read the output from the usb port, but can't convert these raw bytes to sth reasonable.

## What I understand:

- It outputs raw pixels with this line of code
  `UDR0 = (PINC & 15) | (PIND & 240);` in `captureImg` function.
- These pixels are in yuv422 format cause we using these settings `const struct regval_list yuv422_ov7670`.
- Byte order is set to `Y V Y U` cause we are setting `{ REG_COM13, COM13_UVSAT }` in our `yuv422_ov7670`. I've found this info info in [this datasheet](http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/f2016/tools/OV7670_2006.pdf) on page 18.

Maybe I am wrong in sth?

## What I don't understand:

- Why my output has a random size?

  - Before it starts sending pixel bytes it sends `*RDY*` string bytes so I can determine when to start decoding.
  - Code says `captureImg(320, 240)`, which means that there should be 320x240 = 76800 pixels. But the amount of bytes between 2 `*RDY*` commands is sth in range of 79000-79500
- How to convert this `yuv422 YVYU` bytes to rgb?

  - Google says that 2 pixels are encoded into 4 bytes in Y0 V Y1 U order, where V & U are used by both 2 pixels each having a separate Y byte.
  - Another google answer stends that 1 pixel is encoded into 2 bytes, where the first bytes is Y and second has hight 4 bits for V and low 4 bits for U.
  - I've found [this crate](https://crates.io/crates/yuv) which can convert yuv to rgb, but it asks me for `MatrixCoefficients` which I don't know. Inside `yuv422_ov7670` there are some matrix coefficients but how can I understand which are they?

## The code

This is the function which accepts array of bytes, converts each 4 of them to 2 rgb pixels and saves the result with the a help of image crate (thats why half of image is black, I don't have enought bytes to convert).

```
fn decode_and_save(data: &[u8]) {
    let mut imgbuf = image::ImageBuffer::new(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    let mut ix = IMAGE_WIDTH;
    let mut iy = IMAGE_HEIGHT;
    let converter = RGBConvert::<u8>::new(Range::Full, MatrixCoefficients::BT709).unwrap();
    for ch in data.chunks_exact(4) {
        let yuv1 = YUV {
            y: ch[0],
            v: ch[1],
            u: ch[3],
        };
        let yuv2 = YUV {
            y: ch[2],
            v: ch[1],
            u: ch[3],
        };

        let rgb1 = converter.to_rgb(yuv1);
        let rgb2 = converter.to_rgb(yuv2);

        imgbuf.put_pixel(ix - 1, iy - 1, Rgb([rgb1.r, rgb1.g, rgb1.b]));
        imgbuf.put_pixel(ix - 2, iy - 1, Rgb([rgb2.r, rgb2.g, rgb2.b]));
        ix -= 2;

        if ix == 0 {
            ix = IMAGE_WIDTH;
            iy -= 1;
        }
        if iy == 0 {
            break;
        }
    }
    imgbuf.save("./test.png").unwrap();
}
```

As a result of multiple mistakes somewhere in my code I am getting [this result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA2Ki.png).
While the original tool is able to save [this perfect result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF20F.png)

Comment: Please don't tag spamming with `c` and `c++` when your code is in `rust`.

Comment: The code which I am using on arduino and trying to understand  is in `c++`